# Web Browser Control Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, browser

Hello I want to open this website in my windows phone 8 App:

http://www.bukapeta.com/embed.php?peta=155&panel=tool

What i do so far is using this code in my XAML

```
<phone:WebBrowser Source="http://www.bukapeta.com/embed.php?peta=155&amp;panel=tool" />
```

But i dont know why it wont load the website, I make sure the internet connection running smoothly. Any Help ?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I tested your website on my windows phone and it seems it takes a lot of time to load (around 35 seconds for me) because the whole UI is made of svg element and it is not mobile friendly. So maybe you just need to wait a bit longer to see it appear on your screen.

Also, make sure to give your element a name, because sometime this causes some problems.

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="MyBrowser" IsScriptEnabled="true" Source="http://www.bukapeta.com/embed.php?peta=155&amp;panel=tool"/>
```

Comment: So I just need to wait a bit longer ?

Comment: Well, try with another url like "http://google.com". If it shows, you'll be sure that the problem is not from the app but from your website.

Comment: I forgot to tell you to enable javascript because it is disabled by default. See the answer edit.

Comment: THANKS, it appeared now, but after 5 sec it force closed :" Why ? Is it caused by svg element in my website ?

Comment: It says The program '[3520] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -2005270523 (0x887a0005).

Comment: Congratulation. You found a way to crash IE in windows phone. When I tested your website on my phone it crashed and closed IE. I guess your website is using lots of memory than a phone can handle.

Comment: Oh haha IE always crash. Thanks by the way disklosr :D